# API -> add image with external url instead of base64

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, image, media-images

Is there any extension that give us the possibility to add external url instead of a base64 string when I adding/update product via magento 2 api?

Comment: Not sure about it, but what if you convert the img to base 64 using the img url, I think you can do that as well.

Comment: I try to convert the img url to base 64 but magento don't like it :-)
https://imgur.com/oTxMZ7h

Error -> The image content must be valid base64 encoded data.

Comment: nah I mean get the contents of the img url then convert it to base_64

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

an extension is available
you can check this https://github.com/olivertar/m2_api_product_images

also, you can update that as per your need

https://github.com/olivertar/m2_api_product_images/blob/master/Orangecat/MediaGalleryProcessor/Model/MediaGalleryProcessorPlugin.php#L41

remove if condition here and update with following

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents($entry['file']);
if($imagedata){
    $entry['content'][ImageContentInterface::BASE64_ENCODED_DATA] = base64_encode($imagedata);
    $mediaGalleryEntries[$k]['content'][ImageContentInterface::BASE64_ENCODED_DATA] = base64_encode($imagedata);
}
```

Comment: thx for that. But here I need to upload the file in media folder first. I need a external url like https://www.example.com/test.jpeg that I can use in the api

Comment: you can update that with your logic here 
https://github.com/olivertar/m2_api_product_images/blob/master/Orangecat/MediaGalleryProcessor/Model/MediaGalleryProcessorPlugin.php#L40